# Problem with file drag-and-drop in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, drag-and-drop

I'm experiencing some difficulties here.

I have a drop zone (custom view) with it's own class. Everything works great so far with it. The problem is that I can't get the result from the drop operation outside the class of the drop zone.
I read everything I found in the net.

For instance, I would like my drop zone to count the lenght of the Array with the objects (files) dropped and set this number to a NSTextField. I know how to count the array, I don't know how to get this value and set it to the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Send the array to your controller (most probably by having your drop-zone view's header declare a delegate protocol and giving the drop-zone view itself a delegate property, and having the controller conform to that protocol and appoint itself as that delegate), and have your controller send the count to the text field.

Comment: Y. Georgiev: What was confusing about it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused. I got the idea with sending the array to the controller. Maybe my english is too poor to deal with the whole explanation. I really won't bother anyone so only who want, please take a look at my test project. 
[DOWNLOAD 2MB+](http://www.zshare.net/download/80306507ba21f799/)

It should be great if you leave some comments.

Comment: This should be an edit to your question, not a separate response.

Comment: I didn't noticed, sorry about that.